# Material catalog draggable layout stops working when view is added

Tags: java, android, material-components-android

I'm using the DraggableCoordinatorLayout from the Material Components Catalog to create a set of draggable views (material CardView) that can be dragged around like stickers, it works properly when all the views are added before compiling, but when trying to programmatically add new ones the entire layout resets and stops working (views cannot be dragged) as soon as addView() gets called.

layout file, the default_card can be dragged around fine even with multiple cards added

```xml
        <io.material.catalog.draggable.DraggableCoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/cards_holder" app:layout_anchorGravity="center" app:layout_anchor="@+id/cards_holder">
            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:id="@+id/default_card"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="100dp"
                    android:minWidth="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/purple_200"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
            />
        </io.material.catalog.draggable.DraggableCoordinatorLayout>
```

it gets added via a button in the java activity, commenting out `canvasCardsParent.addDraggableChild(tempCard);` still causes the layout to reset but views can still be dragged as normal

```java
    private io.material.catalog.draggable.DraggableCoordinatorLayout canvasCardsParent;
    Button cardButton;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        canvasCardsParent = findViewById(R.id.cards_holder);

        cardButton = findViewById(R.id.button);

                cardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addNewCard();
            }
        });
    }
```

addNewCard() function:

```java
    private void addNewCard(){
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        //create a card and give it an id
        MaterialCardView tempCard = new MaterialCardView(TextEditor.this);
        tempCard.setId(View.generateViewId());
        tempCard.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        //set all parameters
        tempCard.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        tempCard.setMinimumHeight(100);
        tempCard.setMinimumWidth(100);
        tempCard.setY(500);
        tempCard.setX(500);
        tempCard.setClickable(true);
        tempCard.setFocusable(true);


        //add it to the viewport, set as child and refresh the layout
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            canvasCardsParent.addView(tempCard);
            canvasCardsParent.addDraggableChild(tempCard);
            canvasCardsParent.requestLayout();
        });
    }
```

tried:

- adding other types of children that are not material cards (same result)
- adding new card to a different parent (no effect, view gets added and draggable layout works as usual)
- running .bringToFront() in the newly added view and the parent
- not doing .invalidade() and requestLayout() on the parent
- removing the parent from the base xml and programmatically creating it instead
- moving the entire function inside a runOnUiThread() block
- removing the runOnUiThread() block in there
- adding layoutParams to the newly created card